# control key plus S to save

Tags: c#, save, controls, key

I'm trying to implement a shortcut for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save in my project.

How can I acomplish this?

Here's my code:

```
 case Keys.ControlKey:
 // if control + S then save
```

Thanks!

Comment: What language are you writing this in?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:
Control is a modifier so I need to go by the letter "G" (or whatever letter I assign to the save function) and then check whether a modifier was selected or not. Here's the code:

```
private void MainForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

            switch (e.KeyCode)
            {
     case Keys.G:
                        if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
                        {
              //Do something
                        }
                            break;
             }
         }
```